# Google Chrome Removal and Installation

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, windows-registry, intune

I am working on a script to uninstall Google Chrome and Reinstall it via Intune (Microsoft Endpoint Manager). Recently, we've had so many problems getting Chrome updated as it keeps producing errors.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcTm8.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlVRK.png)

According to the official Google Chrome update error page, the error code is due to "An error occurred while checking for updates: Download failed." The suggested fix does not do anything as well as anything else found on the internet. The only thing that seems to fix it is force uninstalling Chrome and deleting every trace of the app in the registry. To do I've created a script so far in my testing the script works at uninstalling Chrome but doesn't work in deleting any registry keys as well as won't reinstall Chrome.

My script:

```
Start-Transcript "C:\Intune Packages\Google Chrome\Installer\log.txt"

Write-host "Closing all instances of Google Chrome..."
cmd /c taskkill /IM Chrome.exe /F

#Identify version and GUID of Google Chrome
Write-host "Identifying Google Chrome location..."
$AppInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name Like 'Google Chrome'"
$ChromeVer = $AppInfo.Version
$GUID = $AppInfo.IdentifyingNumber
Write-host "Google Chrome is installed as version:" $ChromeVer
Write-host "Google Chrome has GUID of:" $GUID


#Uninstall using MSIEXEC
Write-host "Attempting uninstall using MSIEXEC..."
& ${env:WINDIR}\System32\msiexec /x $GUID /Quiet /Passive /NoRestart


#Uninstall using Setup.exe uninstaller
Write-host "Attempting uninstall using Setup.exe uninstaller..."
If(Test-Path -Path C:\Progra~1\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\){
    Write-host "Google Chrome is installed as 64-bit program..."
    & "C:\Program Filses\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level --force-uninstall
}
If(Test-Path -Path C:\Progra~2\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\){
    Write-host "Google Chrome is installed as 32-bit program..."
    & "C:\Program Filses (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level --force-uninstall
}


#Uninstall using WMIC
Write-host "Attempting uninstall using WMIC..."
wmic product where "name like 'Google Chrome'" call uninstall /nointeractive


#Look for Google Chrome in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\
Write-host "Deleting Google Chrome folder from HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\"
$RegPath = "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\"

$ChromeRegKey = Get-ChildItem -Path $RegPath | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -match "Google Chrome"}
    
Write-Host "Product name found:" $ChromeRegKey.ProductName
Write-Host "Folder name found:" $ChromeRegKey.PSChildName

If(!$ChromeRegKey.PSChildName){
    Write-Host "Google Chrome not found in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\"
}
If($ChromeRegKey.PSChildName){
    $ChromeDirToDelete = "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\" + $ChromeRegKey.PSChildName
    Write-Host "Google Chrome directory to delete:" $ChromeDirToDelete
    Remove-Item -Path $ChromeDirToDelete -Force -Recurse
}

Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\AppID\{708860E0-F641-4611-8895-7D867DD3675B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\GoogleUpdate.PolicyStatus" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\GoogleUpdate.PolicyStatus.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{1B9063E4-3882-485E-8797-F28A0240782F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{6DFFE7FE-3153-4AF1-95D8-F8FCCA97E56B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{DDD4B5D4-FD54-497C-8789-0830F29A60EE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{FCE48F77-C677-4012-8A1A-54D2E2BC07BD}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{9F3F5F5D-721A-4B19-9B5D-69F664C1A591}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{1B9063E4-3882-485E-8797-F28A0240782F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{6DFFE7FE-3153-4AF1-95D8-F8FCCA97E56B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{79E0C401-B7BC-4DE5-8104-71350F3A9B67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{DDD4B5D4-FD54-497C-8789-0830F29A60EE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{FCE48F77-C677-4012-8A1A-54D2E2BC07BD}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.htm\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.html\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.shtm\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.webp\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.xht\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.xhtml\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\AppID\{4EB61BAC-A3B6-9581-655041EF4D69}\" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{9465B4B4-5216-4042-9A2C-754D3BCDC410}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\GoogleUpdate.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{9D6AA569-9F30-41AD-885A-346685C74928}\InprocServer32HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoCreateAsync" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoCreateAsync.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoreClass" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoreClass.1" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CredentialDialogMachine" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CredentialDialogMachine.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachine" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachine.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachineFallback" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachineFallback.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassSvc" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassSvc.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.ProcessLauncher" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.ProcessLauncher.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3COMClassService" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3COMClassService.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachine" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachine.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachineFallback" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachineFallback.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebSvc" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebSvc.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{084D78A8-B084-4E14-A629-A2C419B0E3D9}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{0CD01D1E-4A1C-489D-93B9-9B6672877C57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{128C2DA6-2BC0-44C0-B3F6-4EC22E647964}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{18D0F672-18B4-48E6-AD36-6E6BF01DBBC4}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{19692F10-ADD2-4EFF-BE54-E61C62E40D13}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{1C642CED-CA3B-4013-A9DF-CA6CE5FF6503}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{247954F9-9EDC-4E68-8CC3-150C2B89EADF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{2D363682-561D-4C3A-81C6-F2F82107562A}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{2E629606-312A-482F-9B12-2C4ABF6F0B6D}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{31AC3F11-E5EA-4A85-8A3D-8E095A39C27B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{3D05F64F-71E3-48A5-BF6B-83315BC8AE1F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{494B20CF-282E-4BDD-9F5D-B70CB09D351E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{49D7563B-2DDB-4831-88C8-768A53833837}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{4DE778FE-F195-4EE3-9DAB-FE446C239221}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{4E223325-C16B-4EEB-AEDC-19AA99A237FA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{5B25A8DC-1780-4178-A629-6BE8B8DEFAA2}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{6DB17455-4E85-46E7-9D23-E555E4B005AF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{76F7B787-A67C-4C73-82C7-31F5E3AABC5C}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{79E0C401-B7BC-4DE5-8104-71350F3A9B67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{8476CE12-AE1F-4198-805C-BA0F9B783F57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{909489C2-85A6-4322-AA56-D25278649D67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{B3A47570-0A85-4AEA-8270-529D47899603}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{BCDCB538-01C0-46D1-A6A7-52F4D021C272}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{D106AB5F-A70E-400E-A21B-96208C1D8DBB}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{DAB1D343-1B2A-47F9-B445-93DC50704BFE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{DCAB8386-4F03-4DBD-A366-D90BC9F68DE6}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{DD42475D-6D46-496A-924E-BD5630B4CBBA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{FE908CDD-22BB-472A-9870-1A0390E42F36}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{25461599-633D-42B1-84FB-7CD68D026E53}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4EB61BAC-A3B6-4760-9581-655041EF4D69}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{534F5323-3569-4F42-919D-1E1CF93E5BF6}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{598FE0E5-E02D-465D-9A9D-37974A28FD42}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6F8BD55B-E83D-4A47-85BE-81FFA8057A69}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{7DE94008-8AFD-4C70-9728-C6FBFFF6A73E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8A1D4361-2C08-4700-A351-3EAA9CBFF5E4}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9465B4B4-5216-4042-9A2C-754D3BCDC410}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9B2340A0-4068-43D6-B404-32E27217859D}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9D6AA569-9F30-41AD-885A-346685C74928}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{ABC01078-F197-4B0B-ADBC-CFE684B39C82}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B3D28DBD-0DFA-40E4-8071-520767BADC7E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{E225E692-4B47-4777-9BED-4FD7FE257F0E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{084D78A8-B084-4E14-A629-A2C419B0E3D9}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{0CD01D1E-4A1C-489D-93B9-9B6672877C57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{128C2DA6-2BC0-44C0-B3F6-4EC22E647964}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{18D0F672-18B4-48E6-AD36-6E6BF01DBBC4}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{19692F10-ADD2-4EFF-BE54-E61C62E40D13}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{1C642CED-CA3B-4013-A9DF-CA6CE5FF6503}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{247954F9-9EDC-4E68-8CC3-150C2B89EADF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{2D363682-561D-4C3A-81C6-F2F82107562A}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{2E629606-312A-482F-9B12-2C4ABF6F0B6D}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{31AC3F11-E5EA-4A85-8A3D-8E095A39C27B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{3D05F64F-71E3-48A5-BF6B-83315BC8AE1F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{494B20CF-282E-4BDD-9F5D-B70CB09D351E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{49D7563B-2DDB-4831-88C8-768A53833837}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{4DE778FE-F195-4EE3-9DAB-FE446C239221}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{4E223325-C16B-4EEB-AEDC-19AA99A237FA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{5B25A8DC-1780-4178-A629-6BE8B8DEFAA2}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{6DB17455-4E85-46E7-9D23-E555E4B005AF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{76F7B787-A67C-4C73-82C7-31F5E3AABC5C}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{8476CE12-AE1F-4198-805C-BA0F9B783F57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{909489C2-85A6-4322-AA56-D25278649D67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{B3A47570-0A85-4AEA-8270-529D47899603}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{BCDCB538-01C0-46D1-A6A7-52F4D021C272}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D106AB5F-A70E-400E-A21B-96208C1D8DBB}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{DAB1D343-1B2A-47F9-B445-93DC50704BFE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{DCAB8386-4F03-4DBD-A366-D90BC9F68DE6}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{DD42475D-6D46-496A-924E-BD5630B4CBBA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{FE908CDD-22BB-472A-9870-1A0390E42F36}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ActiveSync\WebAuth\Gmail" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseDesktopAppManagement\S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-000\MSI\{A49A0C51-914A-36A0-B6C2-D34A4BF8710A}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\ThrottleCache" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList\chrome.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\GoogleUpdate.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{18635495-7837-4E21-AAE0-78E9D85A7805}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{21C02D29-38ED-478E-9D06-6C2F4C21CF75}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone\NonPackaged\C:#Program Files (x86)#Google#Chrome#Application#chrome.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\ARP" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Micrsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Inventories\0000900334a13d6d54fa42b947e821487ea200000904\Name - Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications\Google Chrome - Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilties" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\RegsiteredApplications\Google Chrome - Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\gupdate" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\gupdatem" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\GoogleChromeElevationService" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\gupdate" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\gupdatem" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKU:\S-1-5-19\SOFTWARE\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKU:\S-1-5-20\SOFTWARE\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue


Remove-Item -Path "C:\Program Filses\Google\Chrome\" -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Program Filses (x86)\Google\Chrome\" -Force -Recurse

Write-host "Uninstall operations have all completed." -fore green

start-process msiexec.exe -argumentlist "/i .\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi /Quiet /Passive /NoRestart"
```

Stop-Transcript
I've tested the script without uploading through Intune and it also doesn't work to remove the registry keys or reinstall Chrome.

[picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJyOy.png)

[picture4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7NRB.png)

Comment: That's a lot of logic you use for Intune. I hope to play with Intune more in the future but will something like `$pkg = "\\server\packages\Google Chrome\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi";
Start-Process $pkg -ArgumentList '/quiet' -Wait;` not work to full resolve with repair of the issue? Seems like a bit too much manual cleanup of reg keys and such for a simple uninstall and reinstall. Try just a reinstall with just simple logic and the latest MSI and see if simplifying it helps you any.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle the clean-up is required because we've found a simple uninstall fails to work as it should for some reason. So when we go to reinstall the app it errors and the only fix is to clean the registry then the reinstall will work. With Intune, the script and the MSI are packaged together so it was supposed to call the MSI installer after the clean-up was done but it does not. So the command you put will not work as is not calling the installer from a different location. But in any case, even running the file locally on a computer pointed to the same directory doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, sounds like a mess. Good luck and thanks for the clarifying points. I suspect it's a permission issue with the reg keys not being removed with the security context of the package using Intune. Is there a way to copy the package to the local machine drive and then run against that package and script on the local file system using `SYSTEM` as the security context to remove the keys and install? Can you tell Intune to do this at startup and run as a startup process locally against the files.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle coping locally doesn't remove the registry keys even when running logged in a local administrator. When running through Intune it automatically runs as System. But it's not a permission issue as if I use Revo Uninstaller Pro i can remove the keys (for those found). Or manually deleting the keys one by one. I unfortunately think it has something to do with the script itself.

Comment: Can you provide a download of the text file that contains the detail from `Start-Transcript`  for download and review for what it captures when running and it does not work?  The transcript may hold some clues so I'd start by making it available for review here with a download link on a free platform like pastebin, etc.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle log accessible from https://pastebin.com/ppJ7Gpy6

Comment: I see a typo here but still digging through it for other obvious things: https://i.imgur.com/RvtVnyZ.png. Here's something else but google this and add that as a path with the command and then run the delete command so get through errors at this level too https://i.imgur.com/MyeR0Sv.png. I meant some reg paths not reg settings with that `New-PSDrive` command just add the `HKCU`, `HKU`, etc. per the format you find with Googling it. I'll say start with ironing those out, and if there is still trouble, give a link to a new transcript log after you run it with those fixes.

Comment: Thanks for finding those typos I clearly missed that but I am creating an updated script where I will add the New-PSDrive first. I will likely set those aside from the HKLM.